# Renamed folder still shows up in Explorer - How to clear Windows Folder Cache?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

I have renamed "Downloads" folder to "OldDownloads" from my D: Drive, and when I issue dir command in command line, I see that Downloads folder is renamed to OldDownloads and when I try to issue command "cd downloads" I get an error.

However, when I open Windows Explorer, I still see Downloads folder and I dont see OldDownloads folder.

When I double click on any file inside "Downloads" folder, I get an error saying file does not exist. I wrote a custom c# command line program to access file from "OldDownloads" folder, I can access it fine.

It seems, folder is successfully renamed, but however Windows Explorer still remembers old folder name and gives wrong path to programs.

Comment: After a reboot still?

Comment: @JanDoggen, After Reboot, Check Disk and Disc Clean, Logout, Login.. still same.

Comment: Run CHKDSK. Maybe the NTFS journal is broken somewhere.